# Google Sheets QUERY function COUNT problem with date in data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a strange problem with the Google Sheets QUERY function and COUNT. I made an easy example to show the problem:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wA5c-1NYpKZ58d6It728EGbTCeRfEzXd_JXN02U0odg/edit?usp=sharing

When there is no date (01.01.2021) in the data, everything works fine. If there is a date in the data the QUERY function stops working/counting. It starts counting again below the date.

/EDIT: Screenshots:

### No date, works fine

[image: No date, works fine]

Function (red cell):

```
=query(A2:C5;"SELECT COUNT(A) WHERE A='a' AND C='Yes' LABEL COUNT(A)''")
```

### With date, stops working

[image: With date, stops working]

Function (red cell):

```
=query(A9:C12;"SELECT COUNT(A) WHERE A='a' AND C='Yes' LABEL COUNT(A)''")
```

### Still counts below the date

[image: Still counts below the date]

Function (red cell):

```
=query(A16:C19;"SELECT COUNT(A) WHERE A='b' AND C='Yes' LABEL COUNT(A)''")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
=query(A9:C12;"SELECT COUNT(A) WHERE A='a' AND C='Yes' LABEL COUNT(A)''";0)
```

You need the `;0` header at the end.

Comment: Thank you, it works! The function used the row with the date as the header and started counting below that row.